# Android Native Crash: /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (_Z16bionic_trace_endv)

Tags: android, crash, native

My App always crashed by the same problem but I could not find the reason.Help me please!

Mostly, it appread on Android10 or Android11 devices.

Stacktrace below:

Process Name: 'com.netease.intelligent.debug'
Thread Name: 'ReferenceQueueD'

```
pid: 12603, tid: 12617  >>> com.netease.intelligent.debug <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
  r0 00000000  r1 00003149  r2 00000006  r3 bb110c88
  r4 bb110c9c  r5 bb110c80  r6 0000313b  r7 0000016b
  r8 bb110c88  r9 bb110c98  10 bb110cb8  fp bb110ca8
  ip 00003149  sp bb110c58  lr e4cfcecd  pc e4cfcee0  cpsr 008e0030
  d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
  d16 b18e40886ac388f0  d17 c6dfba755a1de0b5
  d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
  d20 0000000100004101  d21 64656c62616e655f
  d22 c3f56773ba060229  d23 4bfbb900f7d31bbe
  d24 ec41d4e1ec41d4e1  d25 ec41d4e1ec41d4e1
  d26 dc93e00d8985fd9a  d27 3c20b4da04eaec76
  d28 8cd6505a568c540d  d29 252ac7263313fa83
  d30 4478480100656c62  d31 0000003f0000003f
  scr 20000010

    #00  pc 00010ee0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (_Z16bionic_trace_endv)
    #00  pc 00010ee0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so
    #01  pc 00010ecd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so
    --- --- ---
    00 pc 00010ee0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so
    01 pc 00010ec9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so
--- --- ---
    --- --- --- ---

memory near r1:
    00003148 -------- -------- -------- --------  ................

memory near r3:
    bb110c48 bb110d50 bb110c80 0000313b 52f20000  P.......;1.....R
    bb110c58 bb110cc8 bb110cd8 bb110ce8 bb110cf8  ................
    bb110c68 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110c78 00000000 00000000 ffffffdf ffffffff  ................
    bb110c88 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 0000313b  ............;1..
    bb110c98 0000281f 00000000 00000000 00000000  .(..............
    bb110ca8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cd8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110ce8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cf8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d18 e83be000 bb110d50 bb110d50 e4d74400  ..;.P...P....D..
    bb110d28 52f20000 00000000 00000000 e4d5c380  ...R............
    bb110d38 18e85000 e4cf271b 52f20000 e4cf2b25  .P...'.....R%+..

memory near r4:
    bb110c5c bb110cd8 bb110ce8 bb110cf8 00000000  ................
    bb110c6c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110c7c 00000000 ffffffdf ffffffff 00000000  ................
    bb110c8c 00000000 ffffffff 0000313b 0000281f  ........;1...(..
    bb110c9c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cbc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110ccc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cdc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cfc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d0c 00000000 00000000 00000000 e83be000  ..............;.
    bb110d1c bb110d50 bb110d50 e4d74400 52f20000  P...P....D.....R
    bb110d2c 00000000 00000000 e4d5c380 18e85000  .............P..
    bb110d3c e4cf271b 52f20000 e4cf2b25 e3b29e10  .'.....R%+......
    bb110d4c e4cf2ba7 e83be000 00001000 0000003b  .+....;.....;...

memory near r5:
    bb110c40 bb110d50 bb110c80 bb110d50 bb110c80  P.......P.......
    bb110c50 0000313b 52f20000 bb110cc8 bb110cd8  ;1.....R........
    bb110c60 bb110ce8 bb110cf8 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110c70 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110c80 ffffffdf ffffffff 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110c90 ffffffff 0000313b 0000281f 00000000  ....;1...(......
    bb110ca0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cb0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cc0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cd0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110ce0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cf0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d00 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d10 00000000 00000000 e83be000 bb110d50  ..........;.P...
    bb110d20 bb110d50 e4d74400 52f20000 00000000  P....D.....R....
    bb110d30 00000000 e4d5c380 18e85000 e4cf271b  .........P...'..

memory near r6:
    00003138 -------- -------- -------- --------  ................

memory near r8:
    bb110c48 bb110d50 bb110c80 0000313b 52f20000  P.......;1.....R
    bb110c58 bb110cc8 bb110cd8 bb110ce8 bb110cf8  ................
    bb110c68 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110c78 00000000 00000000 ffffffdf ffffffff  ................
    bb110c88 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 0000313b  ............;1..
    bb110c98 0000281f 00000000 00000000 00000000  .(..............
    bb110ca8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cd8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110ce8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cf8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d18 e83be000 bb110d50 bb110d50 e4d74400  ..;.P...P....D..
    bb110d28 52f20000 00000000 00000000 e4d5c380  ...R............
    bb110d38 18e85000 e4cf271b 52f20000 e4cf2b25  .P...'.....R%+..

memory near r9:
    bb110c58 bb110cc8 bb110cd8 bb110ce8 bb110cf8  ................
    bb110c68 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110c78 00000000 00000000 ffffffdf ffffffff  ................
    bb110c88 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 0000313b  ............;1..
    bb110c98 0000281f 00000000 00000000 00000000  .(..............
    bb110ca8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cd8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110ce8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cf8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d18 e83be000 bb110d50 bb110d50 e4d74400  ..;.P...P....D..
    bb110d28 52f20000 00000000 00000000 e4d5c380  ...R............
    bb110d38 18e85000 e4cf271b 52f20000 e4cf2b25  .P...'.....R%+..
    bb110d48 e3b29e10 e4cf2ba7 e83be000 00001000  .....+....;.....

memory near sl:
    bb110c78 00000000 00000000 ffffffdf ffffffff  ................
    bb110c88 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 0000313b  ............;1..
    bb110c98 0000281f 00000000 00000000 00000000  .(..............
    bb110ca8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cd8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110ce8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cf8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d18 e83be000 bb110d50 bb110d50 e4d74400  ..;.P...P....D..
    bb110d28 52f20000 00000000 00000000 e4d5c380  ...R............
    bb110d38 18e85000 e4cf271b 52f20000 e4cf2b25  .P...'.....R%+..
    bb110d48 e3b29e10 e4cf2ba7 e83be000 00001000  .....+....;.....
    bb110d58 0000003b 0000003a e3b29e10 00070100  ;...:...........
    bb110d68 52f20000 e4cf3983 00070100 52f20000  ...R.9.........R

memory near fp:
    bb110c68 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110c78 00000000 00000000 ffffffdf ffffffff  ................
    bb110c88 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 0000313b  ............;1..
    bb110c98 0000281f 00000000 00000000 00000000  .(..............
    bb110ca8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cd8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110ce8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110cf8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
    bb110d18 e83be000 bb110d50 bb110d50 e4d74400  ..;.P...P....D..
    bb110d28 52f20000 00000000 00000000 e4d5c380  ...R............
    bb110d38 18e85000 e4cf271b 52f20000 e4cf2b25  .P...'.....R%+..
    bb110d48 e3b29e10 e4cf2ba7 e83be000 00001000  .....+....;.....
    bb110d58 0000003b 0000003a e3b29e10 00070100  ;...:...........

memory near ip:
    00003148 -------- -------- -------- --------  ................

code around pc:
    e4cfcea0 8acff900 0040f108 f9009000 20148acf  ......@........ 
    e4cfceb0 8ac0f904 30fff04f 8acff90a 8acff90b  ....O..0........
    e4cfcec0 8acff909 900e960f ed12f04e 90102100  ........N....!..
    e4cfced0 46306021 22064639 f2404643 df00176b  !`0F9F."CF@.k...
    e4cfcee0 4821a904 4478460a 0acdf960 0acdf942  ..!H.FxD`...B...
    e4cfcef0 60106800 22002006 ef12f04e 46292002  .h.`. ."N.... )F
    e4cfcf00 f04e2200 2014ee6e ec92f04e 20e04605  ."N.n.. N....F. 
    e4cfcf10 ec8ef04e 98034606 f90a4644 f9008acf  N....F..DF......
    e4cfcf20 98028acf 8acff90b 8acff900 f9099801  ................
    e4cfcf30 f9008acf 98008acf 8acff900 f9042014  ............. ..
    e4cfcf40 f04f8ac0 950f30ff f04e900e 2100ecd2  ..O..0....N....!
    e4cfcf50 60219010 46314628 46432206 176bf240  ..!`(F1F."CF@.k.
    e4cfcf60 207fdf00 eee4f04e fffe8f76 f04d2300  ... N...v....#M.
    e4cfcf70 460abefb f06f4601 23000063 befaf04d  ...F.Fo.c..#M...
    e4cfcf80 b082b510 4479490b 6821680c 21009101  .....IyD.h!h...!
    e4cfcf90 46699100 eee4f04e 28009900 f04fbf08  ..iFN......(..O.

code around lr:
    e4cfce8c f1080b20 90020910 f9004644 f1088acf   .......DF......
    e4cfce9c 90010050 8acff900 0040f108 f9009000  P.........@.....
    e4cfceac 20148acf 8ac0f904 30fff04f 8acff90a  ... ....O..0....
    e4cfcebc 8acff90b 8acff909 900e960f ed12f04e  ............N...
    e4cfcecc 90102100 46306021 22064639 f2404643  .!..!`0F9F."CF@.
    e4cfcedc df00176b 4821a904 4478460a 0acdf960  k.....!H.FxD`...
    e4cfceec 0acdf942 60106800 22002006 ef12f04e  B....h.`. ."N...
    e4cfcefc 46292002 f04e2200 2014ee6e ec92f04e  . )F."N.n.. N...
    e4cfcf0c 20e04605 ec8ef04e 98034606 f90a4644  .F. N....F..DF..
    e4cfcf1c f9008acf 98028acf 8acff90b 8acff900  ................
    e4cfcf2c f9099801 f9008acf 98008acf 8acff900  ................
    e4cfcf3c f9042014 f04f8ac0 950f30ff f04e900e  . ....O..0....N.
    e4cfcf4c 2100ecd2 60219010 46314628 46432206  ...!..!`(F1F."CF
    e4cfcf5c 176bf240 207fdf00 eee4f04e fffe8f76  @.k.... N...v...
    e4cfcf6c f04d2300 460abefb f06f4601 23000063  .#M....F.Fo.c..#
    e4cfcf7c befaf04d b082b510 4479490b 6821680c  M........IyD.h!h

stack:
    bb110c18:  00000002 e4d53124 00000000 00000000 
    bb110c28:  e4d5c380 0914c659 00000000 00000000 
    bb110c38:  00000000 3ece4c7d bb110d50 bb110c80 
    bb110c48:  bb110d50 bb110c80 0000313b 52f20000 
    bb110c58:  bb110cc8 bb110cd8 bb110ce8 bb110cf8   #sp
    bb110c68:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110c78:  00000000 00000000 ffffffdf ffffffff 
    bb110c88:  00000000 00000000 ffffffff 0000313b 
    bb110c98:  0000281f 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110ca8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110cb8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110cc8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110cd8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110ce8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110cf8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110d08:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110d18:  e83be000 bb110d50 bb110d50 e4d74400 
    bb110d28:  52f20000 00000000 00000000 e4d5c380 
    bb110d38:  18e85000 e4cf271b 52f20000 e4cf2b25 
    bb110d48:  e3b29e10 e4cf2ba7 e83be000 00001000 
    bb110d58:  0000003b 0000003a e3b29e10 00070100 
    bb110d68:  52f20000 e4cf3983 00070100 52f20000 
    bb110d78:  00070100 00000000 e3b29e10 00000000 
    bb110d88:  18e85028 18e84fc0 00000000 db547010 
    bb110d98:  6f982c98 e4cf3887 00000010 db547010 
    bb110da8:  18e84fc0 e465a3f9 b54ba910 18e85028 
    bb110db8:  18e84fc0 dab28d5f dab2b117 18e85028 
    bb110dc8:  18e84fc0 dab2b123 18e84fc0 6ff3f3cb 
    bb110dd8:  b54ba910 00000000 6fb8da70 00000000 
    bb110de8:  00000001 6fb695d8 00000000 00000000 
    bb110df8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110e08:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110e18:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110e28:  00000000 00000000 00000000 18e85028 
    bb110e38:  18e85028 18e84fc0 00000000 6f982c98 
    bb110e48:  18e85000 6ff64a99 6fb804dc dab2b117 
    bb110e58:  00000000 b54ba910 00000000 18e84fc0 
    bb110e68:  18e85028 6fe9cfcd 6facd644 18e65670 
    bb110e78:  00000001 db547010 6f9caa80 e4d53124 
    bb110e88:  6e878190 e371beaf 00000000 00000000 
    bb110e98:  6fa740cc 6f9b6680 18e84fc0 6f982c98 
    bb110ea8:  18e85000 6fd3edfb 6fa740cc 18e84fc0 
    bb110eb8:  3ece4c7d 00000000 1932edd0 6f9b6680 
    bb110ec8:  18e84fc0 6fd3eed7 6fa740e8 e387e403 
    bb110ed8:  6fb5f918 6f9b6680 6f982c98 00000000 
    bb110ee8:  00000000 6f9caa80 6fb5f918 1932edd0 
    bb110ef8:  bb110f6c 6ff752f7 6fb84b70 1932edd0 
    bb110f08:  6f9caa80 6fb5f918 6fb5f8e0 00000002 
    bb110f18:  bb110fa8 6ff4b4cd 6fb7b524 6fb5f918 
    bb110f28:  00000000 00000000 00000000 6fb5f918 
    bb110f38:  14b802a0 6fdd4cdb 6fb02bc0 00000000 
    bb110f48:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000030 
    bb110f58:  e2fa22ca e3476bd7 00000000 12d1b750 
    bb110f68:  00000000 00000001 00000030 e2fa22ca 
    bb110f78:  00000002 e4d53124 bb110fe8 bb110fa8 
    bb110f88:  00000000 e389c295 bb111090 00000000 
    bb110f98:  bb110fe8 bb110fa8 00000004 db547010 
    bb110fa8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110fb8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110fc8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110fd8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb110fe8:  00000000 12d1b750 00000000 00000000 
    bb110ff8:  3ece4c7d bb111040 6fb02bc0 db547010 
    bb111008:  bb111060 bb111090 db5470bc e4d53124 
    bb111018:  bb111160 e34cf2a3 bb111090 e2fa22c9 
    bb111028:  000027ea e3ac1780 00000000 e4d53124 
    bb111038:  e344eedf e38ae914 00000000 00000000 
    bb111048:  00000000 e4cf661b 3ece4c7d e2fa22c9 
    bb111058:  bb1110ac 6fb02bc0 bb111100 e4d53124 
    bb111068:  12d1b750 00000000 bb111160 e37a7e85 
    bb111078:  bb111090 e2fa22c9 14b30000 00000005 
    bb111088:  00000000 bb111150 00000000 00000000 
    bb111098:  00004101 e2fa22c9 00000001 00000004 
    bb1110a8:  bb1110ac 12d1b750 00000000 00000000 
    bb1110b8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb1110c8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb1110d8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb1110e8:  00000000 00000000 3ece4c7d 00000005 
    bb1110f8:  bb111160 bb111150 00000000 bb111160 
    bb111108:  e38ae914 e4d53124 e38ae260 e37a7f93 
    bb111118:  00000000 db547010 e3be4b30 6fb02bc0 
    bb111128:  00000005 e37ea4a3 00000000 00005000 
    bb111138:  00000022 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 
    bb111148:  bb1111c0 e345a409 00000021 00000014 
    bb111158:  c98eb6f0 00430000 db547010 e3be4b30 
    bb111168:  e3ac1780 db547010 00000043 0000005c 
    bb111178:  00000000 00000000 3ece4c7d bb1111c0 
    bb111188:  bb1111c0 bb1111c0 00000078 0000313b 
    bb111198:  e4d53124 bb1111fc e4d53124 e4d4573d 
    bb1111a8:  e4d45713 e4cfe3ef bb1111c8 e4d45713 
    bb1111b8:  bb1111c0 00000000 d09de1c0 bb0081c0 
    bb1111c8:  00003149 0000313b 00000001 bb00c000 
    bb1111d8:  001051c0 00001000 00000000 00000000 
    bb1111e8:  00000003 00000000 e37ea05d db547010 
    bb1111f8:  00000000 80001204 00000000 e447e000 
    bb111208:  00000000 bb1111c0 00000001 00000000 
    bb111218:  bb00c000 00109000 bb00d000 00107000 
    bb111228:  63617473 6e615f6b 6c745f64 32313a73 
    bb111238:  00373136 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb111248:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb111258:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb111268:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb111278:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb111288:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb111298:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb1112a8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb1112b8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb1112c8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb1112d8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb1112e8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    bb1112f8:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
[DEBUG] reach max continuously zero line count: 12!
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---

/data/app/com.netease.intelligent.debug-QMlUViRBThqfGbsd4zixvg==/lib/arm/libmap-lib.so: 912f99f6c01174dfaab8abd0bd72ebdde2b5a59e
/data/app/com.netease.intelligent.debug-QMlUViRBThqfGbsd4zixvg==/lib/arm/libuuid-lib.so: 27850a4bd6b2a77500af64cb679d9f0da03f696f
/data/app/com.netease.intelligent.debug-QMlUViRBThqfGbsd4zixvg==/lib/arm/libursandroidcore.so: 975bd7e89b7c077f96ffd7a7c29711d665f77485
/data/app/com.netease.intelligent.debug-QMlUViRBThqfGbsd4zixvg==/lib/arm/libtuyammkv.so: e7c393066f41bc6b09cdfb7056bd1266d1f96086
/data/app/com.netease.intelligent.debug-QMlUViRBThqfGbsd4zixvg==/lib/arm/libjnimain.so: 5b8b32c4a3bc9e5a9e5d7bc8969866be6e45cdfc
/data/app/com.netease.intelligent.debug-QMlUViRBThqfGbsd4zixvg==/lib/arm/libc++_shared.so: 062c84f6da90c5346e6d26986fa578e8f3c7ffd2
/data/app/com.netease.intelligent.debug-QMlUViRBThqfGbsd4zixvg==/lib/arm/libobjectbox-jni.so: ba13f997b840dff2283995a29b7761e8308e3548
/data/app/com.netease.intelligent.debug-QMlUViRBThqfGbsd4zixvg==/lib/arm/libumeng-spy.so: 367bce62e5e206e752debcf462c6772b2587ca97
/data/app/com.netease.intelligent.debug-QMlUViRBThqfGbsd4zixvg==/lib/arm/libcrashsdk.so: 3e36b6fe967b43ab077e9ce24ce71d24a5e70745
```

Can Anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It has something to do with a memory leak.